# github how to checkout production branch

Tags: git, github

I have a private project hosted on github. I have a production branch of that project. I got a new machine and I need to fix something on production. This is what I did.

```
git clone git@github.com:userid/project.git
# now I have master branch
git co -b production
git pull origin production
```

Using the above mechanism I am able to get production branch but I am getting merge conflicts which I do not want to deal with right now.

Is there a cleaner way of jut getting the production branch code on my local machine?

Comment: You appear similarly confused as to what was actually happening with all the branches as I remember being when I was new to git. Taking a look at the graphical branching display of `gitk --all` helped me a lot in getting an idea of what is actually going on.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could checkout directly the remote branch after fetching it

```
git fetch origin
git branch -f production origin/production
git checkout production
```

or shorter:

```
git checkout -b production origin/production
```

or, with [Git 2.23+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309) (Q3 2019) and [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch):

```
git switch production
```

> If `<branch>` is not found but there does exist a tracking branch in exactly one remote (call it `<remote>`) with a matching name, treat as equivalent to
>
> ```
> git switch -c <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>
> ```

You would be directly working from the fetched copy of `origin/production` branch (no conflict there).

By doing

```
git co -b production
git pull origin production
```

You are trying to merge the remote production branch into your master (in a local 'production' branch, which means potentially conflicts if your master has *locally* a different history than the remote origin/production branch.

Answer (score 7):

`git checkout -b production` by itself will checkout a new branch called `production` based on the branch you currently have checked out, the master.

It's likely that what you actually wanted to do was:

```
git checkout -b production origin/production
```